# Mover "X" Cantidad de archivos

Tags: linux

Hola tengo una pregunta
Se pueden mover "x" cantida de archivos.
Ejemplo: tengo 1000 archivos, de esos mil mover por cantidades de 20

Comment: ¿Esta buscando mover archivos mediante la Terminal de Linux? Creo que le faltan detalles a tu pregunta.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105040/how-to-move-the-first-x-files

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.